# How to use color declarations in titles?

Tags: macros, color, titles

How can I use color **declarations** when setting the title of a document?

I tried

```
\title{\color{blue} Colors in typesetting}
```

but I get an error from LaTeX.

***Update:*** The error reads as followed:

```
doc.tex:89: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.89 \begin{document}
```

Can I define a declaration or an environment which works inside `\title`? Or is there a way to enhance the definition of `\title` to accommodate declarations?

***Update 2:*** To give more context, the base class `pandoc` uses here is `beamer`, but it draws in a lot of packages. (`beamer` itself behaves correct as the standard classes.)

*Note:* For technical reasons(*) I do not want to use

```
\title{\textcolor{blue}{Colors in typesetting}}
```

so, as stated above, it must be a color **declaration**.

---

(*) I really use `pandoc` to generate the TeX document from markdown and parameter-taking commands like `\command{text}` will skip "text" if I convert the markdown document to any other output format.

Comment: An open `\color{blue}` statement is 'dangerous'. Bleeding blue colour in to the rest of the document is avoided here due to grouping.

Comment: Which error message do you get?  The solution that @jak123 suggests should be equivalent to `\title{\color{blue}{My Title}}` (I would rather say `\title{{\color{blue}My Title}}`, though).  Unfortunately, I'm away from my desktop, now, so I cannot check with a compiler.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti See my updates to the question.

Comment: You need to give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) . With any class that I have tried, including `beamer`, using `\title{\color{blue}...}` works fine.

Comment: With the KOMA-classes, you can set font attributes and coloring to a special variable. The title-field really should only contain the title, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there is a package for that, but here is a solution based on redefining the `maketitle` command (for the `article` class).

Create a style file (I saved as `titlecolor.sty`) with the following content (I copied this from the `book.cls` file and add the `\color` command to the title, you can change the format):

```
 \renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \color{blue}{\@title} \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
```

Put `\usepackage{titlecolor}` in your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor} % You need this also of course
    \usepackage{titlecolor}

\title{My title in Blue}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text....
\end{document}
```

Now you will get a coloured title.

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm curious whether there *is* a package to make declarations possible in titles...

Comment: Of course, this patch to `\maketitle` forces a separate title page even if the `notitlepage` option has been specified.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I have no clue if it would. But it is just a redefinition of a class command, why would it behave differently than the original one?

Comment: @jak123: I apologize for not having read your comment until now.  Well, the point is that the `article` class, and many others, *define* the `\maketitle` command in two different ways depending on whether the `titlepage` option has been specified or not; but your patch unconditionally uses the definition valid for `titlepage`.  You should say `\if@titlepage \renewcommand\maketitle{`<def. for titlepage>`} \else \renewcommand\maketitle{`<def. for notitlepage>`} \fi`.  Look closely at the code in `article.cls`.

Answer (score 1):

For standard classes there's the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package.

After the edit to the question, the class used here is `beamer`. In this case, the answer is really simple since beamer provides an easy way to change the color attributes for the title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red,bg=blue}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

In

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red,bg=blue}
```

`fg` stands for foreground and `bg` for background. In my example I changed both for illustration purposes, but ou can change only one of them.